# How to write a function to generate random number 0/1 use another random function?

Tags: algorithm, random, numbers

If I have a function named rand1() which generates number 0(30% probability) or 1(70% probability),  how to write a function rand2() which generates number 0 or 1 equiprobability use rand1() ?

Update：

Finally, I found this is a problem on book Introduction to Algorithms (2nd) (I have bought the Chinese edition of this book ), Excercise 5.1-3, the original problem is :

5.1-3 
Suppose that you want to output 0 with probability 1/2 and 1 with probability 1/2.
At your disposal is a procedure BIASED-RANDOM, that outputs either 0 or 1. It
outputs 1 with some probability p and 0 with probability 1− p, where 0 < p < 1,
but you do not know what p is. Give an algorithm that uses BIASED-RANDOM
as a subroutine, and returns an unbiased answer, returning 0 with probability 1/2
and 1 with probability 1/2. What is the expected running time of your algorithm
as a function of p?

the solution is :
(see: http://www.cnblogs.com/meteorgan/archive/2012/05/04/2482317.html)

To get an unbiased random bit, given only calls to BIASED-RANDOM, call
BIASED-RANDOM twice. Repeatedly do so until the two calls return different
values, and when this occurs, return the Þrst of the two bits:

```
UNBIASED-RANDOM
while TRUE
do
x ← BIASED-RANDOM
y ← BIASED-RANDOM
if x != y
then return x
```

To see that UNBIASED-RANDOM returns 0 and 1 each with probability 1/2, observe
that the probability that a given iteration returns 0 is

```
Pr {x = 0 and y = 1} = (1 − p)p ,
```

and the probability that a given iteration returns 1 is

```
Pr {x = 1 and y = 0} = p(1 − p) .
```

(We rely on the bits returned by BIASED-RANDOM being independent.) Thus, the
probability that a given iteration returns 0 equals the probability that it returns 1.
Since there is no other way for UNBIASED-RANDOM to return a value, it returns 0
and 1 each with probability 1/2.

Comment: Not really 50/50, but 49/51: You can generate with rand1() twice, if both are 1, then you can assign 0; assign 1 for other cases.

Comment: Homework? Interview question?

Comment: today's interview question, I have no ideas.

Comment: @JensGustedt - I don't think it does.  `rand()` is a generic function, not specific to C.  Have removed the C tag.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566/your-favourite-maths-puzzles/580#580

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generate two numbers, `a` and `b`.

If `a` is 0 and `b` is 1 (21% chance), generate a 0.
If `a` is 1 and `b` is 0 (21% chance), generate a 1.

For all other cases (58% chance), just generate a new `a` and `b` and try again.

Comment: And what's the probability that this algorithm doesn't terminate? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB And the probability that it doesn't terminate after N calls to `rand1` is `0.58^N`.

Comment: @Qnan: OK - and the expected number of rounds?

Comment: @KerrekSB it's a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution for the number of runs, with p=0.42. So the mean is 1/p, or roughly 2.38.

Comment: +1 It is a rejection technique that by virtue of symmetry, is exact, though it may not be as efficient as desired.

Comment: +1 This rejection techniques is more efficient than a sampling technique (along the lines of draw `n` samples and then decide), and it is more accurate, since there is no statistical error around decision.  Also - it's very easy to code: draw pair until decision...

Comment: @mcxiaoke - this IS exact. The only flaw is it may (rarely) take an arbitrarily long time before you get a result.

Comment: @mcxiaoke Exactly 21% for either of the two cases we handle, if you eliminate all other cases by retrying, the end result is _exactly_ 50% either way.

Comment: This is called whitening a random sequence.  This is by far the most common method described, but it is not the most efficient.  See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29545/whitening-a-random-bit-sequence/29558#29558)

Answer (score 4):

If you call `rand1` twice, there is an equal chance of getting `[1 0]` and `[0 1]`, so if you return the first of each non-matching pair (and discard matching pairs) you will get, on average, `0.5(1 - p2 - (1-p)2)` output bits per input bit (where `p` is the probability of `rand1` returning `1`; 0.7 in your example) and independently of `p`, each output bit will be 1 with probability 0.5.

However, we can do better.

Rather than throw away the matching pairs, we can remember them in the hope that they are followed by opposite matching pairs - The sequences `[0 0 1 1]` and `[1 1 0 0]` are also equally likely, and again we can return the first bit whenever we see such a sequence (still with output probability 0.5.)  We can keep combining them indefinitely, looking for sequences like `[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]` etc.

And we can go even further - consider the input sequences `[0 0 0 1]` and `[0 1 0 0]` produce the same output (`[0]`) as it stands, but these two sequences were also equally likely, so we can extract an extra bit of output from this, returning `[0 0]` for the first case and `[0 1]`
for the second.  This is where it gets more complicated though, as you would need to start buffering output bits.

Both techniques can be applied recursively, and taken to the limit it becomes lossless (i.e. if `rand1` has a probability of 0.5, you get an average of one output bit per input bit.)

Full description (with math) here: http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/coinflipext.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Below `rand2` function will provide 50% probability for occurence of zero or one.

```
#define LIMIT_TO_CALCULATE_PROBABILITY 10 //set any even numbers

int rand2()
{
    static int one_occurred = 0;
    static int zero_occured = 0;
    int rand_value = 0;
    int limit = (LIMIT_TO_CALCULATE_PROBABILITY / 2);

    if (LIMIT_TO_CALCULATE_PROBABILITY == (one_occured + zero_occured))
    {
        one_occured = 0;
        zero_occured = 0;
    }

    rand_value = rand1();   

    if ((1 == rand_value) && (one_occured < limit))
    {
        one_occured++;
        return rand_value;
    }
    else if ((0 == rand_value) && (zero_occured < limit))
    {
        zero_occured++;
        return rand_value;
    }
    else if (1 == rand_value)
    {
        zero_occured++;
        return 0;
    }
    else if (0 == rand_value)
    {
        one_occured++;
        return 1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This will produce *correlated* outputs, which is usually undesirable.

Comment: If we keep the LIMIT_TO_CALCULATE_PROBABILITY  as less as possible, then the correlated outputs occurence will be very less.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to figure out how close you want to get to 50% 0 50% 1.

If you add results from repeated calls to rand1. if the results is 0 or 2 then the value returned is 0  if it is 1 then return 1. (in code you can use modulo 2)

```
int val = rand1();   // prob 30%      0, and 70%      1

val=(val+rand1())%2; // prob 58%      0, and 42%      1  (#1 see math bellow)
val=(val+rand1())%2; // prob 46.8%    0, and 53.2%    1  (#2 see math bellow)
val=(val+rand1())%2; // prob 51.28%   0, and 48.72%   1
val=(val+rand1())%2; // prob 49.488%  0, and 50.512%  1
val=(val+rand1())%2; // prob 50.2048% 0, and 49.7952% 1
```

You get the idea. so it is up to you to figure out how close you want the probabilities. every subsequent call will gets you closer to 50% 50% but it will never be exactly equal.

If you want the math for the probabilities:

## 1

```
prob ((val+rand1()%2) = 0) = (prob(val = 0)*prob(rand1() = 0)) + (prob(val = 1)*prob(rand1() = 1)
                           = (0.3*0.3)+(0.7*0.7)
                           = 0.09 + 0.49
                           = 0.58
                           = 58%

prob ((val+rand1()%2) = 1) = (prob(val = 1)*prob(rand1() = 0)) + (prob(val = 0)*prob(rand1() = 1)
                           = (0.7*0.3)+(0.3*0.7)
                           = 0.21 + 0.21
                           = 0.42 
                           = 42%
```

## 2

```
 prob ((val+rand1()%2) = 0) = (prob(val = 0)*prob(rand1() = 0)) + (prob(val = 1)*prob(rand1() = 1)
                            = (0.58*0.3)+(0.42*0.7)
                            = 0.174 + 0.294
                            = 0.468
                            = 46.8%

 prob ((val+rand1()%2) = 1) = (prob(val = 1)*prob(rand1() = 0)) + (prob(val = 0)*prob(rand1() = 1)
                            = (0.42*0.3)+(0.58*0.7)
                            = 0.126 + 0.406
                            = 0.532
                            = 53.2%
```

Comment: I want to know and understand what you wrote, but it hasn't been explained as well according to me

Comment: @ShivanshJagga, The point is that you can determine with absolute precision how many times you need to call val=(val+rand1())%2 to get a final value that distribution that is close to 50% 0, and 50% 1 as you decide. I show that after 6 calls you are at 50.2% 0, 49.8% 1. If you need a better distribution then do it a few more times. Do the math yourself. I very much like finnw answer too.